# flask-pagination : Number of rows not returned | Pagination doesn't work

Tags: python, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

I am not able to successfully paginate the records.
[image]
[***This is the link from where I got the flask-pagination help.***](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/#how-to-use)

My view function looks like this (**NOTE** : I have only shown the relevant code):

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask.ext.paginate import Pagination

mod = Blueprint('runserver', __name__)

@app.route('/home/all-puppies/<int:shelter_id>/<q>')
def showAllPuppies():
    search = False
    q = request.args.get('q')
    if q:
        search = True
    try:
        page = int(request.args.get('page', 1))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1

    puppies = session.query(Puppy, Shelter).join(Shelter).filter(Shelter.id == shelter_id).all()

    pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=puppies.count(puppies), search=search, record_name='puppies')
    return render_template('allpuppies.html',
                           puppies=puppies,
                           pagination=pagination,
                           )
```

My **`allpuppies.html`** looks like this :

```
{% extends "master.html" %}

{% block title %}All Puppies{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{{ pagination.info|safe }}
{{ pagination.links }}
<table class="table table-condensed" align:"center">
  <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
      <th>D.O.B</th>
      <th>Shelter</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for puppy in puppies %}
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
         <td>{{ puppy.Puppy.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ puppy.Puppy.gender }}</td>
            <td>{{ puppy.Puppy.weight }}</td>
            <td><b>{{ puppy.Puppy.dateOfBirth }}<b></td>
            <td>{{ puppy.Shelter.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ puppy.Shelter.city }},{{ puppy.Shelter.state}}</td>
            <td><a href='{{ url_for('showPuppyDetails', puppy_id = puppy.Puppy.id ) }}'> Details </a></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
{{ pagination.links }}
{% endblock %}
```

---

***EDIT : 1***
I changed my query to filter out `puppies` in a particular shelter only. For that I changed my `@app.route()` to have the `shelter_id` also as a query string parameter. I also added `<q>` to the route as the first line of that view function is `q = request.args.get('q')`. But when I do this change, it gives me an BuildError as follows  :

> werkzeug.routing.BuildError
>
> BuildError: ('showAllPuppies', {'shelter_id': 2}, None)

Answer (score 0):

A little late on the answer, but the total is a seperate query that works with the module as a keyword.  I would try a seperate query.

```
total = puppies = session.query(Puppy, Shelter).join(Shelter).filter(Shelter.id == shelter_id).count()
```

Then pass total into Pagination as total=total